# Why is $\hat y_i=\hat\beta_1-\hat\beta_2x_i$?

Tags: statistics, regression

I'm trying to show that $\hat\sigma^2 =\frac{\sum\hat\epsilon^2}{n-2}$ is an estimator without biais and I started with:

$$\hat\epsilon_i=y_i-\hat y_i$$

and my teacher suggested me to use the formula I gave in the title, which works to demonstrate what I am looking for, but which I don't understand.

Thus why is $\hat y_i= \hat\beta_1-\hat\beta_2x_i$?

what frustrates me the more is why does the $x_i$ doesn't have an hat, like its little friend $y_i$?

Comment: $x_i$ does not have a hat because it is taken from your sample. The goal is to find a predicted value of the dependent variable for each $x_i$ in the sample. $\hat{y}_i$ stands for the predicted value corresponding to $x_i$, and $\hat{y}_i = \hat{\beta}_1+\hat{\beta}_2 x_i$.

Comment: Your equation has no residuum $e_i$. It is $\hat y_i=y_i-e_i$. The equation becomes $y_i-e_i=\hat \beta_1-\hat \beta_2x_i\Rightarrow y_i=\hat \beta_1-\hat \beta_2x_i+e_i $ Now you have the equation for the sample data points. In general you minimize $\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n  (y_i-\hat y_i)^2$

Comment: Do you mean I should add the residuum?